# How to copy faster to flash device?

Tags: flash, drive

I am using a flash drive and my USB's filesystem is FAT.
It is very slow while copy files  or paste files into it.
In windows i can do these operation much faster using Teracopy software. 
Is there any packages or any commands to do these operation much faster in Linux?

Comment: That is a long standing issue that never got resolved as far as I know. Some devices from some manufacturers are blamed for bad signaling, but there was also recently a [post from a kernel maintainer](https://plus.google.com/116960357493251979546/posts/RZpndv4BCCD) about similar topic that makes me think that there might still be an issue in the code. http://askubuntu.com/search?q=usb+speed

Answer (score 0):

you could get a new asus router with USB 3.0 will work with fat32 or fat, but the info travel as fast as you wireless or wired connection!

Answer (score -2):

FAT is old. You should convert your USB's file system to NTFS to improve speed.

Comment: Prejudice is the wrong way to finding a solution. FAT is a simple filesystem and does a good job for what it was designed. On the other side NTFS wasn't designed for USB flash devices.

Comment: I am using an USB with NTFS filesystem.

Comment: On top of that, the Linux NTFS drivers are still not up to scratch, so it'll be even *slower* than copying to FAT, if anything (unless something's changed in the last year or so, which it may well have).